# Rails seeding cities and areas tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application where there are standard cities and areas rows that I want to have initialized in my tables in production and development. I have the data in separate files in array form. 
Example cairo_areas.txt file has the following:

```
["Downtown - Abdin",
"Downtown - Abu El Rish",
"Downtown - Ahmed Helmy",
"Downtown - Ahmed Maher",
"Downtown - Gamea' El Banat"]
```

This is only part of the array of course to serve as an example.

Now I've tried to look for the best way to initialize in the database, but most of the answers I found seem very old. 
In short the two approaches I found are:

1. Insert the data in `seeds.rb`. The downside is that most of the data there are for testing purposes, and I'm trying to separate the original data from the Faker data.
2. Approach 2 is to create a task to seed the city and area data into the database, but most of the answers I found are very old in older versions of Rails.

I want to know what is the best way to insert authentic production data into the database at initializing?

Comment: If we need to amend data on production and there's a sizeable amount to import, we normally create a migration that contains all changes

Comment: This way there's some record of the transaction and it's not just someone cowboy'ing around in console

Answer (score 2):

According to what Mark told you on his answer there is a third option which is widely used for adding data to production environments which is creating a migration that creates those records or modifies existing ones.

Two things must be said about the seeds.rb, this file should contain the minimal amount of data, for which according to the business logic of your system, makes the system functional. E.g, creation of roles, permissions and other information which your systems makes no sense without it. Also, this seeds.rb script should be idempotent, so you can re run the seeds.rb at any time without breaking the logic of the data. So you should use Model.find before doing Model.create basically. In that sense you can keep adding information to that seed file and re run it any time.

You might wonder how to choose over a migration or a rake task. I would suggest you to use migrations, because when used correctly you have the possibility to rollback those changes. Option that you do not have when using tasks.

Sorry if I was to verbose, I hope it helps !